# Can this WebGL 2.0 code be compiled using desktop (non-ES) OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I came across the following bit of GLSL code. I've tried compiling it in my OpenGL desktop application, but the compiler says "Unsupported construction":

```
float[] 
    camx = float[] ( .2351, 1.2351, 1.2351, 1., .2, .41, .545,.545, .5,.084,.145,  3.04,.12, .44,.44,.416, -1.404, .21,.2351, .2351),
    camy = float[] (-.094,  .35,     .28,  .38,  .04, .11, -.44,-.44,.35,.0614,.418, 1.,-.96, .67,.8,.0, -1., -.06,-.094),
    camz = float[] ( .608,  .608,    .35,   .3608, -.03, .48,.032,.032, .47,0.201,.05,.28,.3, 1.445,1.,1.4, 2.019, .508,.608),

    lookx = float[] (-.73, -.627, -1., -.3, -1., -.72, -.82,-.82,-.67,-.5,-.07,-.67,-.27, -.35,-.35,-.775, .08, -.727),
    looky = float[] (-.364, -.2,   -.2,  -.2,  0., -.39, -.5, -.5,-.56,-.37,-.96,-.74,-.94, -.35,-.35,-.1, .83,-.364),
    lookz = float[] (-.582, -.582, -.5, -.35, -.0, -.58, -.2776,-.2776,-.48,-.79,-.25,.06,-.18, -.87,-.87,.23, .55, -.582),

    minsx = float[] (-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-1.1, -1.05,-1.05,-1.21,-1.22,-1.04,-0.737,-.62,-10., -.653,  -.653, -.3252),
    minsy = float[] (-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.787, -1.05,-1.05,-.954,-1.17,-.79,-0.73,-.71,-.75, -2.,   -2., -.7862),
    minsz = float[] (-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.095,-0.0001,-0.0001,-.0001,-.032,-.126,-1.23,-.85,-.787, -.822, -1.073, -.0948),
    minsw = float[] ( .69, .69, .69, .69, .69, .678, .678,  .678,.7,.73,1.684,1.49,.833, .627,.77,.826,  1.8976, 1.8899, .69),

    maxsx = float[] ( .35,.3457,.3457,.3457,.3457, .3457,.3457,.3457, 1.05,1.05,.39,.85,.3457,.73,.72,5., .888,  .735, .35),
    maxsy = float[] (1.,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.05,1.05,.65,.65,1.0218,0.73,.74,1.67, .1665, 1.),
    maxsz = float[] (1.22,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215, 1.27,1.4,1.27,1.27,1.2215,.73,.74,.775, 1.2676, 1.22),
    maxsw = float[] ( .84, .84, .84, .84, .84, .9834,.9834,.9834,.95,.93,2.74,1.23,.9834, .8335,.14,1.172, .7798, .84);
```

What do I need to make it run - what OpenGL version, what GLSL version? Is it at all possible? Tried with `#version 130` as well as `#version 450`.

What is this array declaration syntax even called? Because I don't know that, I can't Google it.

Comment: Two downvotes, zero comments? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: how is this not an OpenGL question?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't contain anything OpenGL or WebGL related, it's a general language syntax question.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Because OpenGL, WebGL, and OpenGL ES are not all the same specification. They all have differences between them, and an answer from a desktop OpenGL user may not be appropriate for a WebGL user. Also, what SurvivalMachine said.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: and the syntax is part of the OpenGL system of specifications. Also, it is very much WebGL related because I know this code does run under WebGL 2.0. Not to mention the question explicitly asks how to compile this code in a desktop OpenGL application. The tag stays because it belongs here.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine This is a legit OpenGL question. The code above is GLSL. [See example here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdScW3) . The question seems clear to me. They have a some GLSL ES 3.0 shader code and they want to know how to get it to compile on Desktop OpenGL. How is this a bad question?

Comment: @NicolBolas, the question does have GLSL 300 ES in it. See example of the code working [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdScW3) so it seems like a valid question. The question is "how do I convert this GLSL 300 ES code to GLSL 400" code (or other desktop version). Why is that not a valid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if

```
float[] var = float[](1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

is legal on WebGL, but this:

```
float var[] = float[](1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

is legal in WebGL, OpenGL ES and desktop OpenGL shaders language.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I was hoping to run it as-is, but this is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`WEBGL_debug_shaders`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_debug_shaders/) extension we can see what WebGL is translating the shader to.

On my macOS 10.12.4 MacbookPro with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M it gets translated to

```
#version 410
vec4 webgl_7ee689ba03587a69;
float webgl_c2b306c049a15ae4[20] = float[20](0.2351, 1.2351, 1.2351, 1.0, 0.2, 0.41, 0.54500002, 0.54500002, 0.5, 0.083999999, 0.145, 3.04, 0.12, 0.44, 0.44, 0.41600001, -1.404, 0.20999999, 0.2351, 0.2351),
webgl_868616b3691095da[19] = float[19](-0.093999997, 0.34999999, 0.28, 0.38, 0.039999999, 0.11, -0.44, -0.44, 0.34999999, 0.0614, 0.41800001, 1.0, -0.95999998, 0.67000002, 0.80000001, 0.0, -1.0, -0.059999999, -0.093999997), 
webgl_3e2c7528d4f43c53[19] = float[19](0.60799998, 0.60799998, 0.34999999, 0.3608, -0.029999999, 0.47999999, 0.032000002, 0.032000002, 0.47, 0.20100001, 0.050000001, 0.28, 0.30000001, 1.4450001, 1.0, 1.4, 2.0190001, 0.50800002, 0.60799998), 
webgl_9e68babaf2d04cd6[18] = float[18](-0.73000002, -0.62699997, -1.0, -0.30000001, -1.0, -0.72000003, -0.81999999, -0.81999999, -0.67000002, -0.5, -0.07, -0.67000002, -0.27000001, -0.34999999, -0.34999999, -0.77499998, 0.079999998, -0.727), 
webgl_4df744ca60a7d008[18] = float[18](-0.36399999, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, 0.0, -0.38999999, -0.5, -0.5, -0.56, -0.37, -0.95999998, -0.74000001, -0.94, -0.34999999, -0.34999999, -0.1, 0.82999998, -0.36399999), 
webgl_a51f276969e67935[18] = float[18](-0.58200002, -0.58200002, -0.5, -0.34999999, -0.0, -0.57999998, -0.27759999, -0.27759999, -0.47999999, -0.79000002, -0.25, 0.059999999, -0.18000001, -0.87, -0.87, 0.23, 0.55000001, -0.58200002), 
webgl_bcade59aab63231d[19] = float[19](-0.32519999, -0.32519999, -0.32519999, -0.32519999, -0.32519999, -0.32519999, -0.32519999, -1.1, -1.05, -1.05, -1.21, -1.22, -1.04, -0.73699999, -0.62, -10.0, -0.653, -0.653, -0.32519999), 
webgl_f9a51b2fab8f5627[19] = float[19](-0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.78619999, -0.787, -1.05, -1.05, -0.954, -1.17, -0.79000002, -0.73000002, -0.70999998, -0.75, -2.0, -2.0, -0.78619999), 
webgl_dfe5d0694a0c7e0f[19] = float[19](-0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094800003, -0.094999999, -9.9999997e-05, -9.9999997e-05, -9.9999997e-05, -0.032000002, -0.126, -1.23, -0.85000002, -0.787, -0.82200003, -1.073, -0.094800003), 
webgl_6acb30bd922445d0[19] = float[19](0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.67799997, 0.67799997, 0.67799997, 0.69999999, 0.73000002, 1.684, 1.49, 0.833, 0.62699997, 0.76999998, 0.82599998, 1.8976001, 1.8899, 0.69), 
webgl_7c494107c1e74a02[19] = float[19](0.34999999, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 1.05, 1.05, 0.38999999, 0.85000002, 0.3457, 0.73000002, 0.72000003, 5.0, 0.88800001, 0.73500001, 0.34999999), 
webgl_12fa0dbd667de033[18] = float[18](1.0, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.0218, 1.05, 1.05, 0.64999998, 0.64999998, 1.0218, 0.73000002, 0.74000001, 1.67, 0.1665, 1.0), 
webgl_7b478bc2fbbf2bca[18] = float[18](1.22, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.2215, 1.27, 1.4, 1.27, 1.27, 1.2215, 0.73000002, 0.74000001, 0.77499998, 1.2676001, 1.22), 
webgl_3ecd17680ca66be7[18] = float[18](0.83999997, 0.83999997, 0.83999997, 0.83999997, 0.83999997, 0.98339999, 0.98339999, 0.98339999, 0.94999999, 0.93000001, 2.74, 1.23, 0.98339999, 0.83350003, 0.14, 1.1720001, 0.7798, 0.83999997);
void main(){
(webgl_7ee689ba03587a69 = vec4(webgl_c2b306c049a15ae4[3]));
}
```

```js
const fs = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

vec4 outColor;

float[] 
    camx = float[] ( .2351, 1.2351, 1.2351, 1., .2, .41, .545,.545, .5,.084,.145,  3.04,.12, .44,.44,.416, -1.404, .21,.2351, .2351),
    camy = float[] (-.094,  .35,     .28,  .38,  .04, .11, -.44,-.44,.35,.0614,.418, 1.,-.96, .67,.8,.0, -1., -.06,-.094),
    camz = float[] ( .608,  .608,    .35,   .3608, -.03, .48,.032,.032, .47,0.201,.05,.28,.3, 1.445,1.,1.4, 2.019, .508,.608),

    lookx = float[] (-.73, -.627, -1., -.3, -1., -.72, -.82,-.82,-.67,-.5,-.07,-.67,-.27, -.35,-.35,-.775, .08, -.727),
    looky = float[] (-.364, -.2,   -.2,  -.2,  0., -.39, -.5, -.5,-.56,-.37,-.96,-.74,-.94, -.35,-.35,-.1, .83,-.364),
    lookz = float[] (-.582, -.582, -.5, -.35, -.0, -.58, -.2776,-.2776,-.48,-.79,-.25,.06,-.18, -.87,-.87,.23, .55, -.582),

    minsx = float[] (-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-.3252,-1.1, -1.05,-1.05,-1.21,-1.22,-1.04,-0.737,-.62,-10., -.653,  -.653, -.3252),
    minsy = float[] (-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.7862,-.787, -1.05,-1.05,-.954,-1.17,-.79,-0.73,-.71,-.75, -2.,   -2., -.7862),
    minsz = float[] (-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.0948,-.095,-0.0001,-0.0001,-.0001,-.032,-.126,-1.23,-.85,-.787, -.822, -1.073, -.0948),
    minsw = float[] ( .69, .69, .69, .69, .69, .678, .678,  .678,.7,.73,1.684,1.49,.833, .627,.77,.826,  1.8976, 1.8899, .69),

    maxsx = float[] ( .35,.3457,.3457,.3457,.3457, .3457,.3457,.3457, 1.05,1.05,.39,.85,.3457,.73,.72,5., .888,  .735, .35),
    maxsy = float[] (1.,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.0218,1.05,1.05,.65,.65,1.0218,0.73,.74,1.67, .1665, 1.),
    maxsz = float[] (1.22,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215,1.2215, 1.27,1.4,1.27,1.27,1.2215,.73,.74,.775, 1.2676, 1.22),
    maxsw = float[] ( .84, .84, .84, .84, .84, .9834,.9834,.9834,.95,.93,2.74,1.23,.9834, .8335,.14,1.172, .7798, .84);


void main() {
  outColor = vec4(camx[3]);
}

`

const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
const ext = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_shaders");
const s = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(s, fs);
gl.compileShader(s);
console.log(ext.getTranslatedShaderSource(s));
```